# Custom Action Intent Opens my App in the same context as the app that I clicked From

Tags: android, android-intent

I have searched a lot on this.

But, I have my code working to open my app using a custom intent URL.  This URL is usually delivered via email.

When I click on the link, it opens my app fine and everything seems to be working; however, it opens in the context of the email application.

For example, if I click on the link from Gmail, when I open multitasking, I have to click on Gmail to return back to the app that just opened.

I would think it should open my app and I can continue using Gmail while my other app is running.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This is Android's default behaviour.

Comment: FD_ : i don't know witch android version you are using, but in Jelly bean and Kitkat i have the same problem as Frenzy : Share button start the activity in the current app by default. Thx by the way for this question, i had most difficulty to find an anwer until comming here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your URL look like this:

`intent:#Intent;launchFlags=0x10000000;component=com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyActivity;end`

This URL contains the launchFlag for `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVIY_NEW_TASK`, so this will launch your app in a separate task (outside of the email client or browser or whatever).

---

**EDIT: Add additional details based on OP's comment**

You say that you are using a URL like this: http://com.my.app/5058749

In that case you must have used an Intent filter to get Android to open your app by specifying an `<intent-filter>` on a certain `<activity>` in your manifest. There are several things you can do to deal with the problem of the launched Activity ending up in the same task as the Activity that launched it:

1) If the Activity is always intended to be the root (starting, first) Activity of a task, you can put the following code in `onCreate()` **after** the call to `super.onCreate()`:

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
    // Activity was launched into another task. Restart it in its own task
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return;
}
```

2) You can set the launch mode of this Activity to `singleTask` in the manifest by adding

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

to the `<activity>` definition. This will cause the Activity to be launched in its own task but this launch mode has other consequences that are more subtle and so you need to be careful about using it. In general I don't like to suggest this because it tends to create more problems than it solves.

3) You can determine if your app was launched from the browser or email client by examining the `Intent` used to start it in `onCreate()` (The Intent will have the `data` set to the URL when launched via the browser or email client). You can then decide if you want to restart it in its own task by using the code I've supplied in option 1 above.

Comment: Hey David, I am a little confused:  this is how my url is structured that opens my app while passing an "ID"  http://com.my.app/5058749  in your example, how would it look?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags(`intent.SetFlags()` to your intent. Your actitivty will be opened in a new task and this activity will be the root of your new stack.

Comment: OP is doing this using an URL, he is not calling startActivity() from code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior with android, but to override it, you need to pass

**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**

**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**

with your intent.

Comment: OP is doing this using an URL, he is not calling `startActivity()` from code.